# SQL Query Comparing Date

Tags: sql, date, time

I have a table of items with a 'date_added' column. What I want to do is select all the items added during the last two weeks. How can I do that?

```
 $sql = "SELECT *
           FROM iteminfo
          WHERE quantity > 0
          ORDER BY ID ASC";
 // $query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Post some code, SO is not a "do it for me" kind of site.

Comment: Yup. But I just displayed it according to it's id because I dont have any idea when it comes to time. Here it is:
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM iteminfo  WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY ID ASC";//
$query = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: You should add the code to yout question, click on `edit` option and add there your code. Don't forget to format the code too, so it can be better understandable

Comment: Yes sir! Next time. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MS SQL Server try this code:

```
SELECT tb.date_added
  FROM MyTable tb
 WHERE tb.date_added > DATEADD(week, -2, GETDATE())
```

For MySQL try:

```
SELECT tb.date_added
  FROM MyTable tb
 WHERE DATE_ADD(tb.date_added, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) >= NOW();
```

Comment: You are welcome. If some of the answers given was useful, check the green `Answered` check mark so others know that the question was answered and wich was the correct or useful answer. Nevertheless, next time do a search either on your prefered search engine or here in SO, you will find lot of answers on many subjects as for example http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=sql%20date%20week

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for MySQL):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_ADD(date_added, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) >= NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Date_Added >= DATEADD( week, -2, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be.

Where [Yourdatecolumn]<=GETDATE() AND [Yourdatecolumn]<=DATEADD(DD,-13,GETDATE())

Another option would be

WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, [Yourdatecolumn],GETDATE()) IS BETWEEN 0 and 13

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you want:

```
select item from itemTable
where date_added >= ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL - 14 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on database, but you can try something like this:

```
select * from table where date_added > getdate()-14
```